# Exception in use ExecuteScalar

Tags: c#, ado.net, timeout, executescalar

I want to get a person from database in C# with ADO.net.

I use this command:

```
System.Data.Common.DbCommand command = DatabaseManager.Database.GetStoredProcCommand(proc_name, firstName);
```

and then

```
object personID = DatabaseManager.Database.ExecuteScalar(command);
```

When I click a button, these commands calls two times.

In the first time it is OK. But the second time, I get `TimeOutException`:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding.

I used `command.Disposed();` and `command.Connection.Close();`. But these not resolve my problem.

Please help me how I can resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that some transaction is left open during your first execution of the procedure. This can be either by an error in your procedure or bad connection management in your application.